# Delete duplicates in tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, tuples

I use the following code to create a list of input parameters:

```
xa = Range[-1, 1, 0.05];
ya = Range[-1, 1, 0.05];
xb = Range[-1, 1, 0.05];
yb = Range[-1, 1, 0.05];

crazylist = Tuples[{xa, xb, ya, yb}];
```

However, later these the set of x & y values are used in a symmetric way, that is, for instance:

```
xa = 0.79
xb = 0.14

ya = 0.84
yb = 0.91
```

and

```
xa = 0.84
xb = 0.91

ya = 0.79
yb = 0.14
```

give exactly the same result. Is there any way to get rid of these duplicates. In other words, to delete/not create all but one of these combinations? This could save a lot of calculation time.

I couldn't find a proper solution for this problem online (or didn't understand how to adapt to my problem.)

Best,
Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this does what you are looking for?

A helper function; given a vector of indices $k_1,\dotsc,k_m$ and an integer $n$, it computes vectors of indices $i_1,\dotsc,i_m$ and $k_1,\dotsc,j_m$ so that the $k_\alpha$-th entry in a upper triangular $n\times n$-matrix $A$ is $A_{i_\alpha, j_\alpha}$.

```
LinearToTriangularIndexing[k_?VectorQ, n_Integer] := Module[{i, j},
   i = n - 1 - Floor[Sqrt[4. n (n - 1) - 8. k + 1.]/2.0 - 0.5];
   j = Subtract[
     k + i + Quotient[Subtract[n + 1, i] Subtract[n, i], 2], 
     Quotient[n (n - 1), 2]];
   {i, j}
   ];
```

Now we generate the coordinates list for the `x` which contains all point of an $n \times n$ grid. Arranging *pairs* of elements in `x` in a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix, we only want to read off the entries in the upper triangle.

```
x = Tuples[{xa, xb}];
n = Length[x];
{i, j} = LinearToTriangularIndexing[Range[n (n - 1)/2], n];
pairs = Join[x[[i]], x[[j]], 2];
```

This does not include the diagonal entries. You may add them with

```
pairs = Join[ pairs, Join[x,x,2]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

```
pts = Subdivide[-1, 1., 40]  (* your example has this the same for all *)
prs = Tuples[{pts, pts}]  (* all possible pairs *)
sames = Join[#, #] & /@ prs
xxyy01 = Subsets[prs, {2}]  (* all possible pair of different pairs *)
all=Join[Catenate /@ xxyy01, sames]
Whatever @@@ all  (* do whatever you want with each *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my mathematica version appears to be too old for "subdivide" and "catenate" :-(